# Different buildpacks for worker / web dynos on heroku

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg, worker, buildpack, dyno

In my Rails Apps, I use 2 buildpack :

```
$heroku buildpacks
=== steeple-prod Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/ruby
2. https://github.com/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg
```

but I use ffmpeg only on the worker dyno, not on the web dyno, and I want to use only heroku/ruby on my web dyno, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer from https://twitter.com/schneems https://twitter.com/schneems/status/703219827448545280

> it's not possible right now, you would have to spin up two different apps to run 2 different sets of buildpacks